# Dynamic wallpaper is removed when app is updated

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

My app provides a dynamic wallpaper which is implemented by subclassing the `WallpaperService`. Nothing out of the ordinary there.

My manifest declares the wallpaper like this:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".feature.wallpaper.AppWallpaperService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:label="@string/wallpaper_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
         android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
         android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
</service>
```

Setting the wallpaper from within the app and also via the wallpaper settings of the system works flawlessly.

However when the app gets updated (via Android Studio or Play Store) my wallpaper will be replaced by the default Android wallpaper.

How can I make sure that the wallpaper outlives app updates?

On a side note: system reboots work like a charm.

Comment: Just a guess: If you change the package of an appwidget it will get deleted after the next update. Maybe something similar is going on. You could use the broadcast ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: @qwerty In fact I am already using an broadcast receiver for that broadcast, however for a different functionality. How would one restart the wallpaper service then? Thought this is done by the system for me - after all I also didn't start it in the first place, but left that to the system wallpaper app which is triggered from my app. There the user then clicks "apply" which then starts the wallpaper.